# Word that means short and easy process

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm writing a letter that requires quality diction, and would like to find a word that means a short and easy process. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of words that can be used to *describe* a short and easy process, but I can't think of a word that has that exact definition - off the top of my head. Three words that I can think of are: effortless, elementary, and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the connotation you want to convey, consider **facile**.

> : easily accomplished or attained
>
> **easy**, **facile**, **simple**, **light**, **effortless**, **smooth** mean not demanding
> effort or involving difficulty. **easy** is applicable either to persons
> or things imposing tasks or to activity required by such tasks *an
> easy college course*. **facile** often adds to easy the connotation of
> undue haste or shallowness *facile answers to complex questions*.
> **simple** stresses ease in understanding or dealing with because
> complication is absent *a simple problem in arithmetic*. **light**
> stresses freedom from what is burdensome *a light teaching load*.
> **effortless** stresses the appearance of ease and usually implies the
> prior attainment of artistry or expertness *moving with effortless
> grace*. **smooth** stresses the absence or removal of all difficulties,
> hardships, or obstacles a smooth ride.*

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facile)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking using figurative language would be the best route. You could say, "performed in a snap," or "easy as a piece of cake."